# how to display current user name on navigation bar in nodejs

Tags: node.js

[image]i want to display the current username after "hello" in navigation bar so that it can be seen from any page. I'm using nodejs framework and mongodb as my database. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
i'm getting this error "currentUser is not defined" in header.ejs file

```
<nav id="topNav">
<ul>
  <li id="display" class="brnd"><a href="#">CISCO</a></li>
  <li id="searchBar">
    <form><input class="form-control searchInput" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Item"></form></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hello <%= currentUser.username %></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
    app.use(function(req, res, next){
  var currentUser = req.user;
  next();
});
```

Comment: you will have to pass currentUser.username in your response. can you share your node.js code ?

Comment: It's pretty much this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application

Comment: bro i'm not able to add nodejs code

Answer (score 0):

I think that is ejs template engine that you are using there .  And you are passing a Object to the res.render ? You will have to pass the username to the currentUser object .

Comment: i want to display the username in 4 different urls

Comment: Can you provide the node code snippet where you are sending the final response to user.

Comment: i also want to know the same thing that where i have to pass the the req.user value so that it can be accsessed from any web page

Comment: Can you confirm if you are using ejs for rendering? I guessed it so from the string interpolation in your HTML code. If so, then you will be passing an object when doing a res.render - this is where you can pass your json object with all the content you want to by dynamically displayed on the HTML  - example res.render('index',{}) . You can refer to this post - https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application

Comment: but using res.render("index,{}) i will have to pass that from every route

Comment: Yes, unless you are not refreshing your front end page with every route.

Comment: so is there any other method to make it easy?

Comment: If you are sending a complete HTML page for every route, then I don't see a easy way, you will have to pass that object every time your app renders the ejs. I have built my apps with Angular front end, and I write a service, which holds this data after the first API call - usually the authentication call - and then store this data in the service which I have to use in different angular routes/views.